# defer prerequisite expansion until after a (different) target creation

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I want to be able use the result of a target created in a rule in the prerequisite of another rule in GNU make.  So for example:

```
PREREQ = $(shell echo "reading target1" >&2; cat target1)

target1:
        echo "prereq" > $@

target2: target1 $(PREREQ)
        echo foo > $@
```

`target2` should depend on `prereq` as read from the `target1` file, but that is not in the file until the `target1` recipe is executed.

Granted this is very contrived example with I am sure lots of suggestions about how to refactor this particular example but I'm not looking to refactor this example.  This is just a simplified example of my more complicated problem where I need to derive prerequisites from the contents of a file that is not created until a recipe in the `Makefile` is executed.

The question is, [how] can I make expansion of `$(PREREQ)` (and therefore the execution of the `$(shell cat target1)` defer until after the `target1` rule is actually executed?

Update: I tried `.SECONDARYEXPANSION:` but that doesn't seem to do the job:

```
$ make -d target2
...
reading target1
cat: target1: No such file or directory
...
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'target2'.
 File 'target2' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'target1'.
   File 'target1' does not exist.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'target1'.
  Must remake target 'target1'.
echo "prereq" > target1
[ child management ]
  Successfully remade target file 'target1'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'target2'.
Must remake target 'target2'.
echo foo > target2
[ child management ]
Successfully remade target file 'target2'.
```

As you can see, "reading target" was only printed once at the very beginning demonstrating that `PREREQ` is not expanded again due to the `.SECONDEXPANSION:` and the list of targets *Consider*ed for `target2` did not include `prereq`.

Comment: Sorry, I realized now that it doesn't work as expected. But just to be clear: "secondary expansion" doesn't mean to expand *twice*, but to expand *at the moment of matching* the rule (i.e.: still only *once*). The issue seems to be that the secondary expansion still happens to be performed before the `target1` is created.

Comment: I've deleted the previous answer and added a fresh new potential solution. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Deferring the expansion of the prerequisite `$(PREREQ)` can be achieved by conditionally creating the `target2` and relying on recursion:

```
ifndef expand-prereq
target2: target1
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -f $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) $@ expand-prereq=y
else
target2: target1 $(PREREQ)
    echo foo > $@
endif
```

The first time `make` runs for this makefile, the variable `expand-prereq` is not defined and therefore, the first `targe2` rule is generated as a result of the conditional. This kind of dummy rule makes possible to update `target1` without expanding `$(PREREQ)`.
Matching this rule results in `target1` being updated (since `target1` is a prerequisite of this rule) and `make` being called *recursively* for the same makefile and with `target2` as target.

The second time `make` is (recursively) invoked, the variable `expand-prereq` was defined by means of the command-line argument `expand-prereq=y`, so the second `target2` rule is generated as a result of the `else` branch this time. This rule is the one that actually produces the target `target2`. Note that before this rule can be matched, `target1` has been already created as a side effect of the first dummy rule, so the expansion of `$(PREREQ)` happens after `target1` has been created (what you were looking for).

Answer (score 0):

You could write the complete rule for `target2` to a separate file and `-include` it:

- [Including Other Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html)
- [How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html)

The exact mechanics will depend on your specific use case, and it may well be impossible to achieve what we need using this approach, but it supports a variety of styles for automated dependency generation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions:

1. GNU make 4.4 has been released! Haven't tried yet, but the release notes claim that secondary expansion only expands the prerequisites when they're considered. Furthermore you can delay execution with the .WAIT special prerequisite. That works fine, I tested. If .WAIT really delays the second expansion of the prerequisites after .WAIT, you're good.
2. Recursive make. Restart make after the prerequisites for the second rule were updated. This is a bit lame solution, can't recommend it.
3. Produce the prerequisites into make include file(s). Make automatically restarts after updating include files (re-exec). I'm currently using this method, and it works great. Better than recursive make but still slow, as all the makefiles have to be parsed again. A possible solution is comparing the old and new prerequisites, and only updating the include file, if its content changed. The second rule also needs to be modified to do nothing, if the content changed. Make will run all rules before restarting, but if they don't update their targets, after the restart they'll be executed again, now with the proper prerequisites. An interesting feature of make is that you can define make variables inside a recipe, and use them in other recipes (but not in the prereq list, unless #1 above reall works).